# Can we have windows using Flink's Batch / DataSet API?

Tags: apache-flink

In spite of the question it seems clear that there is no windowing in the DataSet API, but I wonder why that is since conceptually it seems to make sense to be able to process bounded sources and still have window operations.

Am I wrong and is it possible to have windows over a `DataSet`, `UnsortedGrouping` or something similar?

If it's not I guess an alternative would be to use [Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2016/06/13/flink-batch-runner-milestone.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSet API does not provide built-in operators for windowing. The main reason is that it predates the DataStream API and was originally not designed for such use cases. 
However, it provides all building blocks to implement custom windowing logic.

There is also the Table API / SQL, which is a unified API for batch and stream processing. Internally, Table API and SQL queries are translated into DataStream and DataSet jobs. For batch queries, window operations are translated into custom window implementation (as mentioned before), mainly based on `reduceGroup`, `sortPartition`, and `mapPartition`. However, not all window types are supported for batch queries yet.

Apache Beam, which also unifies batch and stream processing, might be a viable option as well.

Comment: Using the Table API was a good suggestion but unfortunately I need a richer windowing API, like the one the DataStream API provides. Is it supposed to be possible to make the following conversions: DataSet -> Table -> DataStream? I'm guessing not since I'm getting a Calcite exception but asking doesn't hurt I guess.

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not possible. However, you can also use the DataStream API on bounded (batch) data. The easiest is to not generate watermarks. When all input is consumed, a MAX_LONG watermark is generated which triggers all processing. That also means that the full data is kept as state until then. You can also implement custom sources that can generate more fine-grained watermarks to avoid large state.